# Regex for change case when click in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to change case when I select part of a text and click in a button in javascript/jquery
this code doesn't work for a selected part

```
$("#button").click(function() {
        value = "some selected text"; 
        value.replace(/\-[a-z]/g, /\-[A-Z]/g);
});
```

output should be:

> SOME SELECTED TEXT

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You know there's a [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) function ?

Comment: i want to put a regex in code to use it in a bbcode textarea if it's not possible put a button to chance case of some selected words

Comment: i didn't know but it needs to be applied in selected words

Answer (score 2):

Here this should work better:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    value = "some selected text"; 
    value = value.toUpperCase();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

```
var lowerText="alphabet";
document.write(lowerText.toUpperCase());
```